# A simulation recursion loop

Tags: python, recursion, simulation

I'm stuck with a Monte Carlo simulation of DLA (diffusion limited aggregation). I won't bore you with detail but an implementation issue I face I believe can be solved with Recursion but I don't know how.

So basically do random walk but once hit the one of the candidates I test the sticking probability, if stick then I break and restart a new walk, if not I want to do continue to walk again but not hitting certain direction that is occupied. So then I check for whether its candidate again, if it is I add to the configuration.

My question is there is no GOTO in python how can I jump back to

```
if tuple(position) in candidates
```

In:

```
N = 18
sinks = np.zeros((N, N))
init_seed = math.floor(N/2)
sinks[-1, init_seed-1] = 1

 num_growth = 100
sticking_prob = 1.0
init_position = [0, init_seed-1]

growth = 0
while growth < num_growth:
    position = init_position
    candidates = list(candidates_matrix(sinks))
    while True:
        choices = ["up", "down", "left", "right"]
        position, flag = simulate_2d_random_walk(position, choices, N)
        if flag == 1:
            break
        
        if tuple(position) in candidates:
            if random.random() < sticking_prob:
                sinks[position[0], position[1]] = 1
                sinks_plot(N, sinks, growth, 1.)
                growth += 1
                break
            else:
                if sinks[position[0]-1, position[1]] == 1:
                    choices.pop(0)
                elif sinks[position[0]+1, position[1]] == 1:
                    choices.pop(1)
                elif sinks[position[0], position[1]-1] == 1:
                    choices.pop(2)
                elif sinks[position[0], position[1]+1] == 1:
                    choices.pop(3)

                position, flag = simulate_2d_random_walk(position, choices, N)
                if flag == 1:
                    break

def simulate_2d_random_walk(position, choices, N):
    # Randomly choose a direction (up, down, left, or right)
    move = random.choice(choices)
    # break flag
    flag = 0
    # Update walker position based on chosen direction
    if move == "up" and position[0] == 0:
        flag = 1
    elif move == "up" and position[0] != 0:
        position = [position[0]-1, position[1]]
    if move == "down" and position[0] == (N-1):
        flag = 1
    elif move == "down" and position[0] != (N-1):
        position = [position[0]+1, position[1]]
    if move == "left":
        position = [position[0], (position[1]-1) % N]
    if move == "right":
        position = [position[0], (position[1]+1) % N]

    return position, flag
```

Comment: A `for` or `while` loop lets you jump back to its first line.

Comment: Recursion only works in functions, where the function calls itself (recurses) until some condition exists, at which point it returns back.

Comment: This is not a comment on the OP, more of a talking-into-the-void question, but what language(s), in 2024, still use `goto` so prevalently that people *miss* `goto` in languages that lack it?

Comment: Is there any moment you want to allow that popped choice again in the rest of the walk?

Comment: *"but not hitting certain direction that is occupied."*:  you disallow at most one of the four directions... what if there are two or three directions that are occupied?

Comment: @trincot total four surrounding grid right? if there are two surrounding grid occupied then I pop out two options. So two direction to go. But that's not what i was asking. I'm asking how to keep walk going if it fail to stick

Comment: @chepner no need for GOTO in python. I'm more asking for a pythonic way to code this just like GOTO. i know GOTO is bad.

Comment: *"if there are two surrounding grid occupied then I pop out two options."*: eh, no, you don't. At most one block of that `if ... elif ... elif ...elif` construct will execute. I know this was not what you were asking, but there are more problems with your code than you think.

Comment: @trincot yeah i found out about this and fixed it. still no recursion

Comment: It is not clear what the flow should be exactly. Like if `tuple(position) in candidates:` is true at first, but then after the "goto" it is no longer true, then what should happen next?  Also, what is "the configuration"?